# Is there an ABI compatibility issue if part of the code of a C project is rewritten in C++, but with the same API left out?

Tags: c++, c, abi

For a shared library project written in C, if I rewrite part of the code in C++, but exactly the same APIs is kept, will I have any ABI compatibility issues?

Comment: This depends on the compiler, but at the least, you will probably need to use an [extern "C"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) specifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you keep the same API (function names and parameter types) you should be good to go.

What you *will* need to do is wrap your header files with this <sub>(copy & pasted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994075/119527))</sub>:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// all of your legacy C code here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This makes sure that the C++ compiler doesn't mangle those names, so the C compiler's extern symbols can still be linked against the exports.